# Xcode 6 Source Control with Assembla fatal: repository 'https://xxx@subversion.assembla.com/svn/xxx/' not found

Tags: xcode, svn

Does somebody has experience with Xcode 6 / Assembla ?
When I want to push or commit files, Xcode seems to contact the repository and then ends up with the following error:
fatal: repository 'https://xxx@subversion.assembla.com/svn/xxx/' not found
although when I add this repository in the preferences, the connection is successful.

Comment: Same issue to me. Did you figure out the issue ?

Comment: No. I have tried everything possible and the support people at Assembla do not know how to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make it work. 
I have to say first that I worked in specific conditions. My environment is Xcode 6 and I decided to work with remote source control in the middle of a project (i.e. with plenty of files in my local computer and no repository). 
At this stage trying to push my local files to Assembla via the Xcode **Source Control** was impossible and Xcode has never been able to commit the files without sending the error message in the title. 
I therefore created a new repository in Assembla. I don't know if the next step is mandatory or not but I also created a local admin user in my Mac with the same credentials used to create the Assembla repository.

Then I launched Xcode and instead of selecting my Project,  I selected in the left pane the option: **Check out an existing project**.
Obviously there was nothing to check out since the repository was empty and all the files were on the local machine. But the checkout was successful and Xcode created the folders branches, tags and trunk which was the most important.

Then I copied all of my local files to the newly created local trunk folder.
I selected Preferences in Xcode and added a new remote repository of the form:
**https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/**

Then I just had to commit all of the files of my project using the **Source Control** of Xcode. That took some time (there were 697 files with all the images) but this is working well.